# Using && in jQuery if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue with getting this to work. This code here works:

```
if ($('.test').is(':visible')) {
    if ($('.test').val() >= 1 )) {
        $(".test .section").show();
        $("#something").hide();
    } else {
        $(".test .section").hide();
    }
}
```

But when I try to add the && operator to specify a range, I get an error saying that its not a function:

```
if ($('.test').is(':visible')) {
    if ($('.test').val() >= 1 && ('.test').val() <= 100)){
        $(".test .section").show();
        $("#something").hide();
    } else {
        $(".test .section").hide();
    }
}
```

I've tried this as well:

```
if ($(('.test').val() >= 1) && (('.test').val() <= 100)))
```

I can't figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: You forgot the `$` in the 2nd `('.test').val()`

Comment: There is an extra closing bracket at `if($('.test').val() >= 1 && ('.test').val() <= 100))`

Comment: i tried with $('.test).val <= 100 too

Comment: should be `if(($('.test').val() >= 1) && ($('.test').val() <= 100)))`

Comment: Please add your HTML to the OP. `$(".test .section")` indicates that `.test` is not an form element. [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns the value of a form element

Comment: @DavinTryon There is still 1 extra ')' in there

Comment: yeah i took that out, still doesn't work

Comment: @StealthSpoder yes there is! Does this look like it: `if(($('.test').val() >= 1) && ($('.test').val() <= 100))`.  (almost looks like Lisp!)

Answer (score 1):

this

```
if(($('.test').val() >= 1) && ($('.test').val() <= 100))
```

You had an extra ) and need to add the $